# Powershell extract value from output

Tags: powershell

In powershell how do I get the value of first row under the the column "Name"

```
PS D:\Users\foo>  Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile | ? IPv4Connectivity -eq "Internet").InterfaceIndex

Name          InterfaceDescription   ifIndex Status   MacAddress   LinkSpeed
----          --------------------   ------- ------   ----------   ---------
Ethernet 8    Foobar #2                    3 Up      zz-zz-zz-zz   5 Gbps
```

The resulting value is "Ethernet 8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell-native commands emit *objects*, (typically) not just *text*.

If the *for-display* output shows column names such as `Name`, the *usual* implication is that the output objects have such a property (predefined *formatting data* may present *calculated* property values with arbitrary names, however)<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
(
  Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex (
      Get-NetConnectionProfile | 
      ? IPv4Connectivity -eq Internet
    ).InterfaceIndex
)[0].Name
```

- `[0]` selects the *first* output object emitted by `Get-NetAdapter`
- `.Name` returns that object's `Name` property value.

Note:

- If your system has no internet-connected adapter, the above command will *fail*, because applying an index such as `[0]` to "nothing" (`$null` or a command that produces *no output*) causes a `Cannot index into a null array.` error.

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell 7.4+, *calculated* properties display *italicized* to indicate that fact.</sup>